# Class Diagram for Asp.net Mvc and C#?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a program that can make class diagrams for C#. I know Visual Studios Pro has a class diagram generator but the couple times I used it I found it limiting in the fact you could not tell it where you wanted to generate the class(Ie if I wanted this class to be in the model folder I would have to manually move it their later and change the namespace).

On top of this since I am not using Pro(I am using Express) I can't use this diagram tool.

So I need a tool that is a standalone application from Visual Studios but still generates the classes and method stubs and allows me to control where they this file will live(ie what folder what is big since I am using asp.net mvc and some class will go in a controller folder and some will go in the model folder).

Anyone know any programs that are preferably free?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this post.

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?QUICKDOC=501

Comment: Hmm I followed that link to the other link the the article that is not a bad program. But I was hoping to have one that allowed you to generate empty classes. Since don't you most of the time make a class diagram before you make a class? Eventhough it is also useful to have it the other way around for classes you did not make class diagrams for.

Answer (score 0):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) is free and open-source. I believe it has a generator.

Comment: However, it does not support generics.

Comment: I can't get it to even to work it says it needs some C# profile to generate. I rather it just be for C# then all the languages under the sun.  Also I need some way to make the controller.cs files.